# Building Multiple Bundles in Angular JS Project using webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

We have a huge angularJS application with different modules as Module 1 and Module 2.My requirement is  how to make different builds for both the Modules using webpack ? for instance if I do **npm build Module 1** (I should only get Module 1 , which we can give to Client 1 ) and module 2 shouldn't be loaded and vice versa.

I have checked 2 concepts in Webpack "Multiple Entry Points and Code Splitting" , Will they help , if So any idea on how to implement these concepts in an already configured Angular application?